# GIF imageview not display when tableview scroll back?

Tags: ios, tableview, cell, gif

I found a very strange thing.

1.I keep a view in my ViewController.
[image]

2. add this view in TableView.

`

```
-(NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return 100;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

    cell.textLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld",indexPath.row];
    if(indexPath.row == 0)
    {
        [cell.contentView addSubview:self.imageContainer];
    }else
    {
        if(self.imageContainer.superview == cell.contentView)
        {
            [self.imageContainer removeFromSuperview];
        }
    }
    return cell;
}

-(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if(indexPath.row == 0)
    {
        return 200;
    }
    else
    {
        return 44;
    }
}
```

when i scroll to bottom and scroll back to top, the gif not display.why?
[image: you can see this picture]

Comment: Please post code as text, not as images

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just change one line code as following and your problem is solved:

from

`if (nil == _imageContainer)`

to

`if (nil == _imageContainer || _imageContainer.superview == nil)`

If there is only one container, in the datasource method, make sure the image is highlighted to get the image loaded. hope it solved your problem.

```
  - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
  UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

cell.textLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld",indexPath.row];
if(indexPath.row == 0)
{

    [cell.contentView addSubview:self.imageContainer];
```

**UIImageView * imageView =   ( UIImageView *) _imageContainer.subviews[0];
        imageView.highlighted = YES;**

```
}else
{
    if(self.imageContainer.superview == cell.contentView)
    {

         [self.imageContainer removeFromSuperview];
    }
}
return cell;
```

}

Comment: Thank you！But I need to save the image Container and add it to the cell. I don't want to recreate the image Container. That's what I need. It's just a small demo. There's probably a lot of stuff in the image Container, and creating one consumes a lot, so I just want to keep one.

Comment: How many containers do you have? I mean how many cells have such container?

Comment: Useful! Just one cell have such container.But imageContainer might have a very deep view hierarchy, and each hierarchy might have pictures. I need to find all the pictures and set them up. It's strange to me. What I want to know is, why is this happening?

Comment: Because there are some codes to load animation of UIImage. These codes are not executed by addSubview( parent view of UIImageView) (i.e. containerView here).  If you set imageView.highlighted, these codes can be called.